# How to delete the vertex on the edge without deleting the edge its on?

Tags: edges

Let’s say vertices V2 as

V1——V2——V3

I want to delete the vertex V2 without deleting the edge V1-V3. So I want it become as below after deleting V2.

V1—————V3

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Another way would be selecting v2 then v3 and use "merge" > "at last"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select vertices you want to delete
2. Press X on your keyboard
3. Select Dissolve Vertices

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case "Dissolve" did something unexpected.

If you want to just remove redundant vertices on a straight line, I believe the proper way is to select it, then shift-select it's neighbor, then right-click and choose *Merge Vertices > At Last* for Blender 2.8.

[image]

Comment: The vertex in question is the orange one on my screenshot, it's located on a straight line between V1 and V3, and no other vertexes are linked to it. Though I'm new to blender, so sorry if my answer is wrong...